# Daniel 9:24-27 earliest copy

Tags: textual-criticism, daniel, manuscript

what is the oldest existing copy of Daniel 9:24-27, and where could I find it?  Thanks!

Comment: Not an answer to your question - but I suspect I know why you are asking this. [This answer](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/29251/what-is-the-meaning-of-seven-weeks-and-threescore-and-two-weeks-in-daniel-92/34634#34634) to a different question might be helpful. Let me know if not and I will take this down.

Answer (score 1):

This will not answer the question completely but provide some information.  A complete list of the Dead Sea Scrolls is found here.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_Dead_Sea_Scrolls

There are numerous fragments and incomplete scrolls of Daniel.  Frustratingly, none contain the text of Dan 9:24-27, although, earlier parts of the same chapter do exist amongst the DSS.

All these Daniel MSS documents date from about 140 to 90 BC (??) and clearly demonstrate that before age and decay had its effect, the book of Daniel then was essentially as we have it today.